# Taking the level path of a url

Tags: javascript

If we have a site `www.testsite.com`

This site have different path under the same domain. I want to check if a thrid level / exists and take the name after /
Example:

```
www.example.com/set1/set2/set3
```

check if this 3 levels path exists and save the set3 to a variable.

Comment: What do you meant by "different path under the same domain"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split()` function with `'/'` as parameter like this :

```
var url = 'www.example.com/set1/set2/set3';
var arrayUrl = url.split('/');
console.log(arrayUrl[3]);
```

Then check if the `arrayUrl[3]` is `null` or `=''`